# Why does the const qualifier allow temporary objects or rvalues?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference, rvalue

Here is a simple function which sums two integers. Now the parameters here are integer references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int sum (int &a, int &b)
{
  return(a + b);
}

int main()

  int a = 23, b = 34;

  cout << sum(a, b) << endl; // this works

  cout<< sum(2, 5) <<endl; // as expected, this does not work; compilation fails

  return(0);
}
```

So it does not work with sum(2, 5) which is understood because there cannot be binding between rvalues (here 2 and 5) and reference variables in the function 'sum'. But it works if the function definition is modified to

```
int sum (const int& a, const int& b)
{
    return (a + b);
}
```

So what change does the const qualifier make that now even refernce variables can bind to rvalues?

Comment: Imagine the following: `void foo(int &a) { a = 7; } int main() { foo(5); }`.  What would that mean?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It would mean the exact same as `int main() {int __tmp=5; foo(__tmp);}`. It would be a no-op, sure, but so is `1+1` as a top-level expression, and it's still not forbidden.

Comment: @user4815162342: You wouldn't expect `foo(a);` to be equivalent to `int __tmp=a; foo(__tmp);`.  Instead, it's effectively equivalent to `5 = 7;`

Comment: @user4815162342 In C++ numerals are constants, so at least it'd be like `const int __tmp=5;`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes I get the point. It is to be ensured that no attempt is made to change values of rvalues, that's why the const. It is not the case if linked to an lvalue as it is basically a memory location storing a value which can change.

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou Good point, although I was referring to intended meaning, not the meaning in current C++, which is exactly as you describe. I wonder how much of C++ would break if the language were changed to treat values as non-constant, allowing the OP's code to compile and be correctly interpreted (as, in that case, a no-op). It is my understanding that a similar change was done for temporaries in C++11?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's understood. The point I was trying to make is that the language would be consistent if it allowed such expressions. Imagine, for instance, if `&7` were a valid expression of type `int *`, forcing the compiler to to allocate space for the constant and yield its address (and pursuant to the usual optimizations in case that address were immediately dereferenced, etc.) In that case, `foo(7)` would be interpreted as `foo(*&7)`. Note that I'm not saying that C++ should have been designed like that, just wondering aloud if there would be negative consequences if it had been.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lvalues represent objects and rvalues represent values (loosely speaking). Binding an rvalue to a non-`const` lvalue reference would allow you to modify the *value* - what exactly does that mean? If you had written `a = 3` in your function, you'd be attempting to modify the value `2` to make it `3`. That just doesn't make sense conceptually. However, `const` lvalue references do not allow modification and only allow you to observe a value, which does make sense.

However, there often are object behind rvalue expressions and it can be useful to modify those objects (such as to steal its resources). This is precisely why the rvalue reference was introduced.

Comment: *"This is precisely why the rvalue reference was introduced."* When binding an rvalue to an lvalue reference is forbidden because it's (porentially) *modifying a value*, why shouldn't the same reasoning apply to rvalue references? As far as I know (from D&E and TC++PL), the rule is because of side-effects, as in `void foo(int&); double d = 32; foo(d);`

Comment: @dyp I'm not sure what you mean with the example, but the reason it doesn't apply is to allow modifications of objects denoted by rvalue expressions. That's because an rvalue expression often does denote an underlying object, even though it *represents* that object's value. The way they get around being able to modify values with rvalue references is by forcing a temporary object to be introduced if you bind something like a literal to a reference. The "lvalues are object, rvalues are values" thing is only really conceptual.

Comment: If rvalues could bind to non-const lvalue references, this example would create a temporary, bind to the `int&`, and leave `d` unmodified (TC++PLv4 p191). (Similarly, `int x; double& d = x;`) The same reasoning is given in D&E p.86 "I made one serious mistake, though, by allowing a non-`const` reference to be initialized by a non-lvalue." Additional reasons are that const-ref vs. by-value is an implementation detail and Fortran compatibility. -- Binding a prvalue to a reference (semantically) always creates an object, even if it is not modified (you can take its address).

Comment: I still don't understand how your reasoning differentiates between rvalue references and const lvalue references.

Comment: @dyp Since rvalues represent values (often the values of temporary objects), we typically have no good reason to modify them, as you pointed out. The side effects wouldn't be observable. But it turns out that there is sometimes a good reason to be able to modify rvalues, which is what rvalue references allow. When we bind an rvalue to an rvalue reference, it creates an object in the case that one doesn't already exist, and we can modify it through that reference.

Comment: @dyp A `const` lvalue reference, on the other hand, is only for observing and will happily accept lvalues or rvalues because observation only requires the value. There's not much you can do with a `const` lvalue reference that requires it to be an object (since you can't modify it), other than take its address. Sorry if I've missed your point.

Comment: And when we bind an rvalue to a const lvalue ref, the same thing happens: An object is created. Consider objects of class type; they can have mutable members etc. I think the reason why it's safe to allow non-const rvalue refs binding to rvalues is that they *cannot* bind to lvalues, too. So we do not have a single reference type that bind to both lvalues and rvalues. *Modifying a value* never happens, it's always an object that gets modified. But the distinction between lvalues and rvalues allows pointing out where side-effects happen.

Answer (score 1):

Rvalues and temporaries behave like **read only** references. So binding them to a non const reference would violate this nature. Declaring a reference as `const` you are fullfilling the read only contract.

On your particular case, the ints 23 etc are called numerals and are inherently constants (have a fixed value). In C++ modifying a constant is undefined behaviour, so your numerals only bind to const references.

Comment: I think 23 and 34 are fine as the values which have ben assigned these values are being used in the function call. It is the second call with numerals 2 and 5 which is problematic as an attempt may be made to change these values in the function 'sum'. So const is required. The 'read only reference' makes sense.

Comment: Not entirely true. Temporaries are not read only. You can execute methods on a temporary and modify it just like any other object.

Comment: @LasseReinhold I mean in terms of argument passing in functions

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou could you elaborate *exactly* what you mean? Until the next semicolon, the temporary is a normal object like any other. You can even do this:

    struct T {
        T() : i(0) {}
        void inc() { i++; } 
        int i;
    };

    T modify(T &t) {
        t.inc();
        return t;
    }

    int main()
    {
        modify(modify(T()));
    }

Comment: @LasseReinhold No you can't. Maybe you're confused by the fact this compiles in VS. In [**gcc**](http://ideone.com/6NSEVY) and [**clang**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d51f3fdacb4d933) compilation fails

Comment: @LasseReinhold To elaborate more : When an object that is returned from a function is not declared constant, it can further change in the same code line in which it is created. For example, it can be used as a current object in interface functions. However, it cannot be passed by address to serve as an argument to any other function. The compiler would refuse to create a local pointer that points to a temporaty object. Maybe I should edit that in the answer to avoid misunderstandings ?

Answer (score 0):

In `sum(2, 5)` 2 and 5 are rvalues.

An rvalue cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference like the one in your first `sum` `int&`, you need `const T&` so later function works for both.

Answer (score -1):

In C++11 you can change it to following to make it always work, regardless what you pass it:

```
int sum (int &&a, int &&b)
{
    return(a + b);
}
```

It will give you a non-const reference to `2` and `5` (i.e. you can modify the values inside the `sum(2, 5)` call though `a` and `b`). This is safe and will not give any weird side effects, even if it had been temporary objects instead of primitives (like `string("foo")`) because the arguments to `sum()` do not have a name. That they don't have a name makes you unable to observe the modification in any way.

Comment: Now you actually broke the line that worked. Check [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/007104837b41fe3f) and [here](http://ideone.com/4cynEH). To have universal references you'd need a function template, check [here](http://ideone.com/cF3SbB). Then again inside the function body an rvalue ref completely changes the game : now the variable is named (ie you'd need `std::move` to forward it to deeper call level) so [this](http://ideone.com/u4o5FN) can compile.